# datejs : can i get the next monday and inject my timestamp

Tags: jquery, date, unix-timestamp

i am using the library [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)
and i am getting next weak days by this:

```
Date.parse('next '+selectedDays[i].day)
```

and its return :

```
Mon Dec 22 2014 11:07:20 GMT+0500 (PKT)10:40
```

1. i want to inject my time instead of `11:07:20`
2. how can i do this
3. and after that i want to convert it into `unix time`

i am building mobile application where i need to make notifications and i have to send unix time according to my setting and my setting is like next "Monday","Tuesday","Friday" at 12:00 Am give me notification.

Comment: everything you asked is documented .... what part of the docs are unclear?

Comment: how to inject my time into the object given by the date.js or give me the link of the documentation where i can read it and understand.

Comment: you already have the link...read the API docs

Comment: by this method? .set({

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the **month**,**year** and **date** from the **object** and create your own **javascript** variable and inject your time in the variable like:

```
    var crdate=d.getFullYear()+'-'+(d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+d.getDate()+' '+s_split_time;
```

s_split_time is your time's variable.